# Getting more information from error message in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

This is an error I commonly get in CI:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /home/... on line ...
```

Is there any way I can get CI to output more information than this?  It would be nice if it would at least output my SQL written as standard SQL not Active Record.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I can get CI to output more information than this?

Check out "**UhOh**" written by Dan Horrigan, a port of Kohana's error handling system for Codeigniter.

- https://github.com/dhorrigan/codeigniter-uhoh
- http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/160969/P0/

Here's a screen shot of UhOh handling a missing view file, so you can get an idea of how cool it is:

[image: Screen shot of error handling]

Comment: Thanks, Wesley.  That's awesome.  I'll check it out.

Comment: Clicking any of those links brings up even more information, it's a really awesome tool - just don't forget to disable it when you go live.